# Android + Card View shadow not displaying in 5.0 emulator?

Tags: android

I'm using the new Card View support lib, and seeing the support "fall-back" version of the shadow on my Card View on older devices.  However, when I launch the app within a 5.0 emulator, I do not see the shadow. Any idea why?

[image: 4.1.2] 
[image: 5.0]

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="#FFFFFFFF"
        app:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
        app:cardElevation="20dp"
        app:contentPadding="0dp" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TEXTVIEW" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Do you have "Use Host GPU" checked in your AVD configuration? Just a guess, but the software graphics emulation may skip the advanced effects.

Comment: That was it, thanks.  Now I'm just curious as to why the card view in older versions adds that padding below the text view?  Any suggestions?

Comment: Can someone add an answer here...